# Rails: Article.all works, class method therein does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How is this possible? `Article.all` works in the console, but a method called `self.retirement_collection` therein does not. Any ideas?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
...
def self.retirement_collection
  articles = Articles.all
  articles.each do |article|
    if article.retirement_at < Time.now
      article.retire
    end
  end
end
...
end
```

I get a `NameError` when I type `Article.retirement_collection` into the console: `NameError: uninitialized constant Article::Articles`.

Comment: `articles = Article.all` ??

Comment: Typo! EUGH. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mistyped the Article class when doing `Article.all`,

```
def self.retirement_collection
  articles = Article.all # Here
  articles.each do |article|
    if article.retirement_at < Time.now
      article.retire
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @emm, Glad to be of help :)